# How to add static field in customize arraylist?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, android-spinner

Hi i am using json parsing in my project. I have following Response and i am setting it to spinner.

```
{"success":1,"languages":[{"id":"2","name":"telugu"},{"id":"3","name":"English"},{"id":"4","name":"Tamil"}]}
```

now issue is that I want to add one id and name static. 
id : 1, name : All

Can any one help me how to add this?

```
 try {
     JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("languages");
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
         try {

             JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
             LanguageModel catobj = new LanguageModel();

             catobj.setLangid(obj.getString("id"));
             catobj.setLangname(obj.getString("name"));

             LanguageModel alldata = new LanguageModel();
             alldata.setLangid(("1"));
             alldata.setLangname(("All"));
             langList.add(0, alldata);
             langList.add(catobj);

         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }

 } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: in your existing JSON ?

Comment: in your Spinner ?

Comment: in my spinner....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that you are adding `id : 1, name : All` inside for loop which would cause it to be added many times. This should be added only once.

Remove following four lines from `for` loop

```
LanguageModel alldata = new LanguageModel();
alldata.setLangid(("1"));
alldata.setLangname(("All"));
langList.add(0,alldata);
```

and put just above `for` statement.

Comment: hi..this one worked for me..but the issue is it showing in spinner , it allows me to select telugu, but when i select english it is not selecting

Answer (score 2):

take this line out of for loop

```
LanguageModel alldata = new LanguageModel();
 alldata.setLangid(("1"));
 alldata.setLangname(("All"));
 langList.add(0,alldata);
```

Comment: hi issue was solved but right now not able to select it ..can you tell?

Comment: where you want to select it? or from where?

Comment: in next screen in toolbar i have spinner, i set arraylist item in that spinner. as a default it sets 'All' , then i chnaged it to telugu it will change, but from telugu if i select next item it does not change and set.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting data from loop and fill and `arraylist`. Just remove this line.

```
LanguageModel alldata = new LanguageModel();
alldata.setLangid(("1"));
alldata.setLangname(("All"));
langList.add(0,alldata);
```